# determining the bounding box around the contours

Tags: matlab

I am trying to determine the bounding box around a specific contour level in the contourf plot:

1. Plot the contourf plot of the data
2. Plot the contour with level 0.075 on the same plot.
3. Extract the contour data from the contour level
4. Calculate the centroid for each contour data
5. Do loop for each element of centroid x y and calculate distance to other 
   centroid x y. Merge Contour data with distances less than threshold of 5, 
   and place it in areas.
6. Replot data and create boxes surrounding area x y data for each area on the 
   same plot.

Here is the code which generates the contourf plot and tries to create bounding box:

```
axes(handles.axes1);
cla(handles.axes1);

contourf(xC(1,:),yC(:,1),zDiff, 200,'LineColor','none');
colormap(handles.axes1,'jet');
colorbar(handles.axes1);
axis equal
caxis([cMin cMax]);
hold on


[Cm,hm] = contour(xC(1,:),yC(:,1),zDiff,[0.075 0.075],'k');
axis equal


Sm = contourdata(Cm);

hwb = waitbar(0.1, 'Processing')

[p,q] = size(Sm);


for i = 1:q

    pts = centroid(Sm(1,i).xdata,Sm(1,i).ydata);
    format long
    centCt(i,1) = pts(1);
    centCt(i,2) = pts(2);
end


[centCxs,indxs] = sort(centCt(:,1));
centCys = centCt(indxs,2);


Se = Sm;

for i = 1:q

Se(1,i).flag = 0;



end


ct = 1;

for j = 1:q
datax = [];
datay = [];
 ct2 = 1;
    for i = 1:q

        rcentd  = sqrt((centCxs(i,1) - centCxs(j,1)).^2 + (centCys(i,1) - centCys(j,1)).^2);

        if(rcentd < 5)
            if(Se(1,i).flag == 0)
              datax = [datax;Se(1,i).xdata];
              datay = [datay;Se(1,i).ydata];

              Se(1,i).flag = 1;


              ct2 = ct2 + 1;

            end

        end
    end

if(ct2 > 5)

     area(ct).xdat = datax;
     area(ct).ydat = datay;
     ct = ct + 1;
end


end


close(hwb);



cla(handles.axes1);    
contourf(xC(1,:),yC(:,1),zDiff, 200,'LineColor','none');
colormap(handles.axes1,'jet');
colorbar(handles.axes1);
axis equal
caxis([cMin cMax]);
hold on

hold(handles.axes1,'on');


for i = 1:length(area)
    [rectx,recty] = minboundrect(area(i).xdat,area(i).ydat);
    plot(rectx,recty,'-k');   
end
```

Initial Contour Picture:

[image]

Results I am getting:

[image]

Desired Result:

[image]

Comment: Try to understand the result you get, using the [matlab debugger](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/debugging-process-and-features.html) may be very helpful. If you understand why you are getting this result, you will probably be able to solve the problem yourself. Providing us a sample image, may also be very helpful for us.

Answer (score 1):

the only thing you need to change is the last part where you're computing the bounding boxes:

```
for i = 1:length(area)
    minMaxX = [min(area(i).xdat),max(area(i).xdat)];
    minMaxY = [min(area(i).ydat),max(area(i).ydat)];
    rect = [minMaxX(1),minMaxY(1),diff(minMaxX),diff(minMaxY)];
    plot(area(i).xdat,area(i).ydat,'.')
    rectangle('Position',rect,'EdgeColor','k')
end
```

---

if you will run the whole modified script (which requires [contourdata](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/38863-extract-contour-data-from-contour-matrix-c)):

```
[xC,yC] = meshgrid(-5:0.1:5);
zDiff = abs(peaks(xC,yC));
subplot(121);
contourf(xC(1,:),yC(:,1),zDiff, 200,'LineColor','none');
colormap('jet');
colorbar();
axis equal
hold on

[Cm,hm] = contour(xC(1,:),yC(:,1),zDiff,3 + [0 0],'k');
axis equal

Sm = contourdata(Cm);
[p,q] = size(Sm);
for i = 1:q
    pts = centroid(Sm(1,i).xdata,Sm(1,i).ydata);
    format long
    centCt(i,1) = pts(1);
    centCt(i,2) = pts(2);
end
area = struct([]);
[centCxs,indxs] = sort(centCt(:,1));
centCys = centCt(indxs,2);
Se = Sm;
for i = 1:q
    Se(1,i).flag = 0;
end
ct = 1;
for j = 1:q
    datax = [];
    datay = [];
    ct2 = 1;
    for i = 1:q
        rcentd  = sqrt((centCxs(i,1) - centCxs(j,1)).^2 + (centCys(i,1) - centCys(j,1)).^2);
        if(rcentd < 1.5)
            if(Se(1,i).flag == 0)
                datax = [datax;Se(1,i).xdata];
                datay = [datay;Se(1,i).ydata];

                Se(1,i).flag = 1;
                ct2 = ct2 + 1;
            end
        end
    end

    if(ct2 > 1)
        area(ct).xdat = datax;
        area(ct).ydat = datay;
        ct = ct + 1;
    end
end

%
subplot(122);
contourf(xC(1,:),yC(:,1),zDiff, 200,'LineColor','none');
colormap('jet');
colorbar();
axis equal
hold on

for i = 1:length(area)
    minMaxX = [min(area(i).xdat),max(area(i).xdat)];
    minMaxY = [min(area(i).ydat),max(area(i).ydat)];
    rect = [minMaxX(1),minMaxY(1),diff(minMaxX),diff(minMaxY)];
    rectangle('Position',rect,'EdgeColor','k')
end
```

you will get:

[image]